# Rails engine separate route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-engines

I created a simple application with a news module and defined the news as a separate mountable engine (it will be used on other projects too). I need to have the ability to mount the admin and user parts of the engine as separate routes on parent application. Now I can mount the whole engine as

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
     mount Jnews::Engine => "/news"
end
```

but I want to separate admin and user routes on parent app as `/news` for user and `/admin/news` for admins. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on why you want to do this:

1. If you want to keep users and admins as separate code in the news gem - then you probably want to isolate 2 namespaces, and then mount each of those - which might involve having them as separate engines themselves.
2. If what you want is (and this is what I think you mean?) is to have the code shared in the news engine, but accessed at 2 different url's in the main application based on whether the user is a plain user or an admin?  What I would do in that case is something like this:

*in the main application*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   mount Jnews::Engine => "/app"
end
```

*in the engine routes*

```
Jnews::Engine.routes.draw do
    match "/news", :to => "some_controller#some_action"
    match "/admin/news", :to => "some_controller#some_action"
end
```

And then in the main application, based on what the user is (user or admin) you can redirect to either `app/news` or `app/admin/news`

I hope that helps, I am not really sure about doing conditional routing.

However, here is a really good guide for routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

You could perhaps try something along the lines of mounting an engine with dynamic routing?

```
mount Jnews::Engine => ":user_id/news"
```

where you end up with Jnew::Engine routed at either `user/news` and `admin/news`? I have never actually done that, so I don't know if it's possible, however... maybe?

Let me know if any of this helps :)
Cheers